# WCFMetadata tag in ItemGroup of silverlight project file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

This line appears in my Silverlight application cs.project file.

```
<ItemGroup>
<WCFMetadata Include="Service References\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Just wondering if anyone know anything about how it works and why it is there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you right click on the `Service References` node in the Solution Explorer and Pick the `Add Service Reference..` you can add a Service reference to your silverlight project. You will see some additional node in your csproject and under teh Service References folder you will see bunch of auto-generated files that help you connect easily to the service and invoke methods

Then your project will look something like this

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Service References\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Service References\ServiceReference1\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Service References\ServiceReference1\Foo-Web-Services-Bar.disco" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Service References\ServiceReference1\configuration91.svcinfo" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Service References\ServiceReference1\configuration.svcinfo" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap">
      <Generator>WCF Proxy Generator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Reference.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Yours is **empty** because you haven't added any service references

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, these lines appears in a csproj when you try to add a reference to a WCF Service

- Right click on the project name
- Select 'Add reference to service' (I use a non english VS, so it
  could be something similar)

From the state of your lines, I think that you don't have any reference active.
But VS has already created the subfolder where it will store every files needed to define future references. (Look at your project folder and you will find the folder 'Service References'